# Passing a value from controller to view in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

In my controller,

```
model.addAttribute("ppr", completed);
```

I have done a for each loop to calculate the total number of hours of course completed. The variable *completed* is in *double*.

In my html,

```
 <span th:value="${ppr}"> ${ppr} </span>
```

In UI, output is

```
${ppr}
```

I want the output to be my calculated value. For example, 2.5.

May I know how I can pass it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to pass the value from controller to view in spring.

In HTML,

[[${ppr}]]

do the trick.